# Google Sheets - Auto group and sort

Tags: google-sheets, sorting

I've got a bunch of data, in this instance it's lists of fixtures for my son's juniors football team, which I'd like to order for ease.  The age group is split into sub teams, e.g. U10 Reds, U10 Blues etc.  I can order all the fixtures by the sub-team, which is progress.  What I'd really like to do though is order them by date/time of the fixture, but within the sub-teams.  So I've currently got something like this:

| Time | Team |
| --- | --- |
| 9:00 | Blues |
| 9:15 | Blues |
| 9:30 | Blues |
| 9:45 | Blues |
| 10:00 | Reds |
| 10:15 | Reds |
| 10:30 | Reds |
| 10:45 | Reds |
| 9:00 | Whites |
| 9:15 | Whites |
| 9:30 | Whites |
| 9:45 | Whites |

But what I'd like is this:

| Sorted | Team |
| --- | --- |
| 9:00 | Blues |
| 9:15 | Blues |
| 9:30 | Blues |
| 9:45 | Blues |
| 9:00 | Whites |
| 9:15 | Whites |
| 9:30 | Whites |
| 9:45 | Whites |
| 10:00 | Reds |
| 10:15 | Reds |
| 10:30 | Reds |
| 10:45 | Reds |

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Use a formula to copy and sort the data into new columns, or into another tab, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  times, teams, ascending, 
  lambda( 
    sortBy, 
    sort( { times, teams }, sortBy, ascending, times, ascending ) 
  )( 
    map( 
      teams, 
      lambda( 
        team, 
        lambda( 
          sortKey,
          if( 
            len(team), 
            sortKey & team, 
            iferror(1/0) 
          ) 
        )( 
          text(min(filter(times, teams = team)), "HH:mm") 
        ) 
      )
    ) 
  ) 
)(  
  A2:A, B2:B, true 
)
```

Modify the range references `A2:A` and `B2:B` so that they point to the actual locations of times and teams. Formula results will look like this:

| Time | Team |  | Solution | Team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9:00 | Blues |  | 9:00 | Blues |
| 9:15 | Blues |  | 9:15 | Blues |
| 9:30 | Blues |  | 9:30 | Blues |
| 9:45 | Blues |  | 9:45 | Blues |
| 10:00 | Reds |  | 9:00 | Whites |
| 10:15 | Reds |  | 9:15 | Whites |
| 10:30 | Reds |  | 9:30 | Whites |
| 10:45 | Reds |  | 9:45 | Whites |
| 9:00 | Whites |  | 10:00 | Reds |
| 9:15 | Whites |  | 10:15 | Reds |
| 9:30 | Whites |  | 10:30 | Reds |
| 9:45 | Whites |  | 10:45 | Reds |

If you need to sort the data in place, **Insert > Column** for sort keys, and then **Data > Sort sheet** by the new sort key column. You can insert suitable sort keys in the new column like this:

```
={ 
  "Sort keys"; 
  lambda( 
    times, teams, 
    lambda( 
      sortBy, 
      sortBy 
    )( 
      map( 
        teams, times, 
        lambda( 
          team, time, 
          lambda( 
            sortKey,
            if( 
              len(team), 
              sortKey & team & text(time, "HH:mm"), 
              iferror(1/0) 
            ) 
          )( 
            text(min(filter(times, teams = team)), "HH:mm") 
          ) 
        )
      ) 
    ) 
  )(  
    A2:A, B2:B 
  ) 
}
```

The result will look like this:

| Time | Team | Sort keys |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9:00 | Blues | 09:00Blues09:00 |
| 9:15 | Blues | 09:00Blues09:15 |
| 9:30 | Blues | 09:00Blues09:30 |
| 9:45 | Blues | 09:00Blues09:45 |
| 10:00 | Reds | 10:00Reds10:00 |
| 10:15 | Reds | 10:00Reds10:15 |
| 10:30 | Reds | 10:00Reds10:30 |
| 10:45 | Reds | 10:00Reds10:45 |
| 9:00 | Whites | 09:00Whites09:00 |
| 9:15 | Whites | 09:00Whites09:15 |
| 9:30 | Whites | 09:00Whites09:30 |
| 9:45 | Whites | 09:00Whites09:45 |

Note that the sort key formula needs to go the *column label row*, i.e., in row `1` in most spreadsheets.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you! The only question I have is where in the formula do I specify other columns to show based on that function.  For example venue, opponent

Comment: That is a different question that will require a different solution. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)